# 100 GB Missing after failing to install Windows 10

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, high-sierra

After I tried to install Windows 10 on my MacbookPro 2017 (High Sierra 10.13.3) my mac was frozen on step when bootcamp assistant was creating partitions (I had to reboot). After that i lost 100GB of my space. Somehow i realised how to remove this new partion but now I'm still missing my 100 GB of hard drive on primary partition.

Can you please help me to figure out how can i get everything back to normal ? I would like to have just one 500GB partition as few hours ago. 
Here is my disklist:

[image]

And when I try to install windows again bootcamp assistant is giving me this message:

[image]

In case that you need to see my diskutil i will upload that image from application as well:

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please post terminal command results as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terminal application commands to remove `OSXRESERVED` and return the free space to the APFS partition are given below.

```
sudo  diskutil  erasevolume   free  n  disk0s3
sudo  disktuil  apfs  resizecontainer  disk0s2  0
```